# An easy way to deep copy objects in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I am getting an entity over the wire (using oData4j). This entity has properties that map to the properties of an object. If I were to copy the contents of this entity to my object in .net, I would just serialize it into json and deserialize it back to my object. This would have automatically copied properties by name.

In java I found a library org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils

However if I serailize using this library, it puts the @type attribute which is the original type of the object serialized. So this is not possible

```
PersonEntity p =new PersonEntity();
 p.Name="tada";
String json = JsonWriter.objectToJson(p);
LocalPerson lp=  new LocalPerson();
 lp = (LocalPerson)JsonReader.jsonToJava(json);//Fails on this line
```

However I could do this in .net using newtonsoft.json. Is there an easy way to copy the entity properties into my class just by property name?

Comment: Instead of trying to handcraft the serialization/deserialization, can you use the `org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumer` class like how it is done in this [example](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse/odata4j-examples/src/main/java/org/odata4j/examples/consumer/JsonGrabbingConsumerExample.java?r=43ecb7326abc4bf818a9e5f871c3433188f79849)?

Comment: Actually, [Apache Olingo](http://olingo.apache.org/) might be a better choice as an OData Java library.